# Building DockerCompose project in Visual Studio errors our when website projects exist in the solution

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently building a MicroServices project. We split up the Frontend and the Backend in seperate different docker containers.

We've added the frontend projects to the Visual Studio solution as well for easy access by including them as website projects (They are purely angular so don't have a csproj file):

[image: Add Existing Website]

However whenever you now build the Docker-Compose project you always receive this error:

[image: Docker compose error]

Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3202 The project file "C:******************.Platform******.Platform.Frontend.Customer\" was not found.   docker-compose  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets    216

This also happens when the Docker-Compose file doesn't even have a reference to the Website projects.
When I remove the projects from the Solution the build starts working again

Comment: Do you mount `Platform.Frontend.Customer` into the container? Would you be able to post the Dockerfiles?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the Dockerfiles because even without references to the Frontend projects and without anything about them in the DockerCompose file and even without Dockerfiles I still see the same errors

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a workaround available for this issue.
Please check [this comment on DockerTools GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/141#issuecomment-522822258)